# Linux Mint "PPA does not support trusty"

Tags: linux, command-line, linux-mint, repository, apt

ta to the repostitories list in Linux Mint 17.3 but cannot seem to get it to add!

I get the error:

```
'This PPA does not support trusty'
Cannot add PPA: ''This PPA does not support trusty'
```

I have tried with the ppa for VSXu: `ppa:gwibber-daily/ppa` and another I can't remember. This is really frustrating!

Is there a way to set apt to accept 'non-trusty'(?) PPAs?

Comment: Still waiting for a correct answer for this, guys and girls. Can anybody help? Also, I'm not the Linux noob people seem to think. Guessing people are judging by my rep!

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve it by running:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
```

first, to enable 32-bit architecture. Then `sudo apt-get update` and adding the ppa.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue trying to install Wine. I ran

```
sudo apt-get update
```

It then allowed me to add the PPA.

Then I ran apt-get again for Wine and the update again. The second update may or may not have been necessary, but I did it anyway.

I don't know enough about Linux yet to say why it worked or whether the same will work for you, but it worked for me.

Comment: Thanks Joe but I have already tried this. It was the first thing I tried

Answer (score 0):

Try compiling the latest version of gwibber from the official Ubuntu [Gwibber Download project files](https://launchpad.net/gwibber/+download) webpage. Download the gwibber-3.6.0.tar.gz file and extract the contents using Archive Manager. There will be a file in the extracted archive called INSTALL that contains 8 step-by-step instructions for installing gwibber.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and managed to solve it by checking the `Getdeb` repository in my Software Sources dialog box :

[image: Software Sources dialog box]

I was then able to add the ppa.